# Is it possible to insert record through chain foreign key relationship in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have three tables/models :**user**,**employee** and **employee_disability**.

1. **employee** has foreign key **user_id**.
2. **employee_disability** contain **emp_id** foreign key.

Is there a way to perform the following action:

```
$user->employee()->empdisability()->create(['name'=>$name,'percent'=>$percent]);
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank You in advance.

**MODELS**:

```
class user extends Authenticatable{
    public function employees(){
       return $this->hasMany('App\Models\employee','user_id');
    }
}

class employee extends Model{
    public function user(){
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\user','user_id');
    }

    public function empdisability(){
         return $this->hasMany('App\Models\emp_disability','emp_id');
    }        
}

class emp_disability extends Model{
    public function employee(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\employee','emp_id');
    }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function storeDisability(Request $request){
    $user=Auth::user();
    $name=$request->name; $percent=$request->percent;
    $user->employee()->empdisability()->create(['name'=>$name,'percent'=>$percent]);
}
```

Comment: Can you please show your migration and controller.

Answer (score 0):

`$user->employee()` returns the query builder for the employee relation, but what you need is the instance.

This should work, notice the lack of parantheses on `employee`

```
$user->employee->empdisability()->create(['name'=>$name,'percent'=>$percent]);
```

Comment: Will try this out and let u know and thank you very much for your effort.